# Prevent row from being changed after initial write

Tags: excel

I want to be able to set values in a cell but prevent the cell from being changed easily afterwards.

The cell will store a random int and so if the user edits the cell and presses enter a new random int is generated. These id's are mapped to unit tests so updates are undesirable.

How could I solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example for a single cell, cell **B9.**

It assumes that we start with all cells **UNLOCKED**

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B9 As Range
    Set B9 = Range("B9")
    If B9.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, B9) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    B9.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="secret"
End Sub
```

Once a value in entered in **B9,** that cell is locked and the worksheet is protected with the password *secret.*

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**